# Why do I have to click twice to submit a question when Stack Exchange's automated question review has no advice to show?

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, user-interface, asking-questions

This is terrible [UX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_experience). I understand that the motivation behind "Review your question" is quality control, but if there is nothing for me to review, why can't the question be submitted in a single click?

Instead the page jumps back, to draw my attention to possibly this:

[image]

But it doesn't stand out in the UI, and if you didn't read that the button said "Review your question", it's hard to see why the page just jarringly jumped back instead of posting the question.

Is it really important for me to know that the automated system didn't find any way to improve my question?

Does Stack Exchange have metrics to see how often the question passes the quality check in the first go?

To add a minor point, as a veteran Stack Exchange user, the system doesn't have any reviews most of the time (in fact, the only time it had one is today while posting this question where it reminded me that one of `feature-request`, `bug`, .. tags were required).

Comment: You might call it a "terrible UX", I'm sure it prevents that ultimate low quality questions get posted by new users. If anything, this two step posting process might be skipped above certain rep levels. For now I would more call it a minor inconvenience.

Comment: @rene Can you explain the value added to quality control by showing "our automated system checked for ways to improve your question and found none"

Comment: Automated systems tend to be terrible in making the right judgement calls. The value added is that after the system confirmed that the question is free of blatant mistakes it is left to a human being with its intelligence to make the final check before a post is presented to the horde of potential down voters.

Comment: @rene I thought "Review your question" as an action (a button) meant that the system will review my question, not me.

Comment: @rene would you then recommend adding language to the message shown to the user which makes it clearer that they are supposed to manually review it? How about changing the UI to reflect this intention, by putting the preview of the question in spotlight. Please post this as an answer for further discussion, because this intention of the current system is not at all clear.

Comment: Probably the button should be called "I've reviewed my question" but obviously I'm biased.

Comment: At the very least, you shouldn’t have to scroll back down to the bottom of the page to click the button to post.

Comment: I agree that it's bad UX. Since most sites don't require you to click the button twice to post, I **already** re-read the question before posting it, without even thinking about it. And **then** I'm presented with "go read your question again!".

Comment: can anyone explain the benefit of this feature? the issues I've seen (missing tags etc.) were already caught before posting an answer

Answer (score 2):

I'm already perfectly capable of posting reasonably good questions that attract upvotes (yay for me;) but don't have the skillset to edit the html/css to avoid this pointless extra scroll & click.

If it's good to go.. send it, tyvm.
Don't make me scroll & click again like I had to pass some extra intelligence test/captcha to prove I can construct some semblance of a grammatical sentence, or be able to spell - though apparently the review performs no *spel-chek* at all.

I have no idea what criteria the review does use to evaluate, whether it's a spam test or merely excludes waffle-face or cat-induced "fdsfgfdsfdsgfd" posts, but the number of appallingly-constructed wall-of-text or stream-of-consciousness questions that get through & are then closed within minutes proves the 'review' is not really making a difference to overall quality.

Comment: I can absolutely relate but can we delete this "answer"? it makes it seem like there's an answer when really there isn't

Comment: It's meta. Meta is for opinions. This question, as with many "why" questions, can't really have an answer.