# Question asking experience "jump to top" is incredibly annoying

Tags: discussion, design

1. Write question.
2. Scroll down to bottom of page.
3. Click "Review your question" button.
4. Page scrolls to top and tells me my question is ready to publish.
5. I now have to **manually scroll back down** to the bottom of the page to click the button now captioned "Post your question" to actually post the question.

Is this a big thing? No, and that's why it's so incredibly annoying, and so amazing that it wasn't detected and corrected when testing the new question experience. It's terrible UX, that's for sure.

If my question doesn't need to be fixed before publication, please leave my window scroll position alone so I can click the button to actually post the thing.

Comment: or just skip the review page if everything looks ok: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347679/why-do-i-have-to-click-twice-to-submit-a-question-when-stack-exchanges-automate

Comment: I doubt there is [any real usability testing](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2000/08/09/the-joel-test-12-steps-to-better-code/). Statistics is not everything.