# Request layout change ("ready to post" on asking page)

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions

Many Stack Exchange sites (not all) have a quality check when you try to post.  It jumps to the top of the page and puts a box saying it is ready to post (or not).  Then you have to scroll back down to the bottom to click the post button.

It would be slightly more convenient to either put the ready-or-not box next to the button, or move the button to the top next to the box.

Comment: Is this about the Ask Question page? Possible related [The new ask page is now live on the network!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344513/1359324)

Comment: Possible related [Is the algorithm which reviews questions when one clicks "review your question" customizable on a per-site basis?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/363674/1359324), [Why do I have to click twice to submit a question when Stack Exchange's automated question review has no advice to show?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347679/1359324)

Comment: It's not quality check, it's just additional step.

Comment: The title could be more specific.

Comment: @Wicket, yes, related, but not quite a duplicate.  I don't mind the extra step as much as the jump to the top and scroll back to the bottom.  It was quite confusing the first few times.  Even now, a couple of times I've forgotten and closed the browser thinking my question had been posted.

Comment: I think that the post needs working. Consider adding to the question body what you mentioned in the comments. Remember that comments are not intended to hold relevant details, especially in [tag:feature-request]. It might be good to refer to the form elements used in the label shown and add the [tag:asking-question] tag. Also, consider adding annotated screenshots for the problem and the suggestions.